# How do I publish a single Google Scripts function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

So I have a single function that I want to be made available for  ***ALL*** of my Google Sheets.

It is very simple. Simple enough that I'll post it here in it's entirety.

```
function swapMonthAndDay() {
  // The code below will swap the month and day for any Date objects in the selected cells.
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.forEach(function(row, y){
    row.forEach(function(value, x){
      if (value instanceof Date){
        var month = value.getMonth() + 1,
            day = value.getDate();
        value.setMonth(day - 1);
        value.setDate(month);
      }
    });
  });  
  range.setValues(values)
}
```

I was able to get the result that I want via the "test as add-on..." from the run menu. But this is temporary as the term "test" implies. So, this leads me to believe that I need to publish this as a Sheets add-on. But, I really don't want to publish this to the web store. Too many steps, authentications, certificates etc to get there.

[image: Add-ons dropdown]

Comment: You need to copy paste this script in all the sheets. You can do that programmatically via [tag:google-apps-script-api]. But each script is a separate project and needs to be authorized separately, if needed.

Comment: Seeing your script, it seems this can be done with formula: `=arrayformula(date(year(a2:a10),day(a2:10),month(a2:10)))`

Comment: I've been copying and pasting the script to each Sheet. It is way too tedious and is what I am working on resolving.

Comment: A formula will not work with what I want to do. I need the values changed, in place. Most of the sources are from CSVs and an incorrect date format is applied when importing. It is not a setting that can be changed via locale settings.

Comment: Use script(`Utilities.parseCsv`) to import. Then change it by a single script before creating a spreadsheet.

Comment: As you state, the solution is an add-on. You can publish privately, but you still must publish. A weaker solution is a library, and that will still require individual stubbing and authorization. An additional solution would be to create a webapp that you use to handle the can import, preview, and data transformation, and then use its output in your sheets.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've been messing around with publishing it. I've spent 8+ hours at something that I know shouldn't take more than 15 minutes. It is trying to publish it as a Chrome Web store Extension... I don't know why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've finally figured it out.

Turns out, it has nothing to do with the Chrome Web Store. There is the GSuite Marketplace and the old and depreciating Chrome Web store. Currently, the deploy as add-on button links through to the Chrome Web Store deployment flow.

It all relies in the Cloud Project settings.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-for-domains

It needs to be accessed via **`Resources > Cloud Platform project...`**, within the menu when editing the script.

[image]